# Good Client Socket Pool

Tags: java, sockets, pool

I need to manage long running TCP socket connections to an external server from my Java application. I'm looking for a good socket pool so I will be able to re-use the sockets. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have a look at building a socket pool on top of [Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/index.html).

Comment: Though about it, but I had bad experience with it in the past. Also, its code is was not optimised to Java 5/6 - no Generics, no concurrent collections, etc.

Comment: Good point. I guess that is one of the problems with some of the commons projects - collections being another example.

Answer (score 3):

Koders.com has an implementation [here](http://www.koders.com/java/fidC48F31080E7917460C81CF6DF7424660DB666249.aspx?s=socket#L7). I can't vouch for it's functionality, however, so you should run a few tests on it.