# Is there a "Socket Connection Pool" of sorts for Java EE apps?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, pool

I'm writing a JAX-RS web service. It responds to client invocations by:

1. Retrieving some info from a database
2. Making a call to an external server

For 2) the server does not expose a web service interface (i.e. no WSDL interface or REST API). Instead, it uses a custom protocol over TCPIP. I'd like to make client calls from my JAX-RS resource *directly* to this server but I don't want to have to open a connection, authenticate, and close the connection for each call to my JAX-RS resource. Is there a way around this? In other words, is there something like a "socket connection pool" available to Java EE apps? Would I have to use something like an ESB? Or is there an alternative that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way to do this would be to write a **JCA connector** for your external server. JCA is part of the Java EE stack, and is meant exactly for that: to provide inbound and outbound connectivity from the application server to external system. It supports **pooling**, **authentication**, transaction, etc. (Database and JMS broker are accesss through JCA connectors, btw).

Writing such an adapter can however be quite hard. Maybe investigate a lightweight approach which a **generic pooling library** (maybe you find something interesting in commons-pool, or c3p0) may be easier.

Have a look also at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939734/tips-for-using-commons-pool-in-production) about TCP connection pooling.